# Galen Framework: "Message: Command ... failed with exit code 1"

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, galen

I have basic Galen testing set up on a responsive Angular site, running through a simple test on desktop and tablet versions of the site.

I did not build this site and cannot say if Galen ever fully worked properly on the website.  I did myself upgrade Galen from v1.6.3 to v2.2.1 in NPM, which included updating syntax etc in the .test file and two .gspec files.

Almost everything appears to be working fine by the Gulp command I am running in Mac terminal:

```
GALEN_URL=http://localhost:3000/MYSITE/ gulp test:galen-local
```

This runs the test locally (vs SauceLabs).  Via terminal, I see the two tests run, with test criteria printed out, and I get a note that there is a failure on tablet version (it's an easy CSS-related fix for tablet version, and I'm not worried about that).  Also, I am getting the HTML reports for those two tests, written to a local directory.

My problem is the following error message I get after the tests run:

```
========================================
Failed tests:
    Login page on tablet device

Suite status: FAIL
Total tests: 2
Total failed tests: 1
Total failures: 3
There were failures in galen tests
[13:51:04] 'test:galen-local' errored after 11 s
[13:51:04] Error in plugin 'gulp-shell'
Message:
    Command `./node_modules/.bin/galen test tests/galen/tests/local.test --htmlreport galen-reports -DwebsiteUrl=http://localhost:3000/MYSITE/ -DsauceUser=USERNAME -DsauceKey=SAUCEKEY` failed with exit code 1
```

What is `failed with exit code 1`?  I have searched Galen docs, searched the web, and I can't figure out what might be going wrong.  I have no idea what that means.

I can provide more code if needed, but the website is relatively sophisticated and things are abstracted out across many files.

thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have answered my own question just now...

When I removed the test criteria that were failing for tablet version, I got the following in terminal with no "command" error message:

```
========================================
Suite status: PASS
Total tests: 2
Total failed tests: 0
Total failures: 0
[14:24:16] Finished 'test:galen-local' after 11 s
```

I presume the command error message was just a reflection that tests in the overall suite were failing.  Still, it seems odd to me that such an error message would appear after a `Total failed tests: 1 Total failures: 3` message already made clear that certain tests in the tablet version were failing. And I still don't know what specifically the "error code 1" above means.

If anyone has any insight, feel free to chime in.  Otherwise, I'll mark this as THE answer at some point, if I don't just delete the entire question.